# Text in title bar buttons

Tags: gnome, steam, text, unity-2d, menu-bar

This "NORMAL" text appears in the bar where the minimize and close buttons:

[image: this "NORMAL" text appears in the bar where the minimize and close buttons]

Answer (score 4):

If you have an Nvidia card in your system, this could be the G-Sync visual indicator. It's something that is seen rarely, but can be an issue. To resolve it, follow these steps:

1. Open your Nvidia X Server Settings panel (or `nvidia-settings` from terminal)
2. Go to "X Screen 0" ⇢ "OpenGL Settings"
3. Uncheck the "G-Sync Visual Indicator"

[image: Nvidia X Server Settings]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I made a minor change to your answer. If you don't approve you can roll it back or change it again. Thanks.